# Vertical Align Element in Bootstrap col

Tags: html, css

I have a setup just like the one I replicated.
I wanted to put the checkbox vertically aligned in the middle (same height as the other col) so it doesn't look so strange.

Any idea how to achieve this?

```css
label {
  display: block !important;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>Hello</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hello" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    World
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by giving the row a `display: flex` then you should reset the label's margin.

Then you could center the div by either using `margin: auto 0;` or `align-self: center;` both will work. I would also recommend upgrading to bootstrap 4. Here is a tool to help you [upgrade to bootstrap 4](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/)

```css
label {
  display: block !important;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.align-self-center {
  align-self: center;
  /*  margin: auto 0;  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>Hello</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hello" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6 align-self-center">
    <label>
                <input type="checkbox" />
                World
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
label {
  display: block !important;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row{
   display:flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>Hello</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hello" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    World
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```